# Refactoring some Unit Test that have lots of repeated code.

Tags: javascript, testing, timezone

I am working on writing some some tests for a function I wrote: the current code works as I would expect it but now I need to DRY my code and refactor. 
Below you will see the unit tests I've writtern:

```js
QUnit.test('Localized Date in Honolulu', assert => {
  const stub = sinon.stub(constantDate, 'getTimezoneOffset', () => {
    return '600';
  });
  console.log('timeSet', timeSet());
  assert.strictEqual(timeSet(), '2017-07-29T14:00:00.000Z', 'there needs to be a message here');
  stub.restore();
});

QUnit.test('San Francisco Date and Time', assert => {
  const stub = sinon.stub(constantDate, 'getTimezoneOffset', () => {
    return '420';
  });
  assert.strictEqual(timeSet(), '2017-07-29T17:00:00.000Z');
  stub.restore();
});

QUnit.test('Sydney time', assert => {
  const stub = sinon.stub(constantDate, 'getTimezoneOffset', () => {
    return '-600';
  });
  assert.strictEqual(timeSet(), '2017-07-30T10:00:00.000Z', 'Expected the time in Sydney to be 10AM');
  stub.restore();
});
```

Although it seems to me that I should be able to refactor the stub I'm finding challenging because every stub has a different return value every time. Can I please get some suggestions as to how I can make my code clean and DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion would be to use partial functions. As you're aware, the first two parameters in `sinon.stub` are the same for every unit test. So, before the unit tests execute we can create a function

```
const timezoneOffsetStub = (callback) => {
   return sinon.stub(constantDate, 'getTimezoneOffset', callback);
}
```

(This assumes `constantDate` is a variable defined globally)
So now to stub in each unit test, we only have to define what the different callbacks are.

```
QUnit.test('Localized Date in Honolulu', assert => {
  const stub = timezoneOffsetStub(() => '600');
  ...
});

QUnit.test('San Francisco Date and Time', assert => {
  const stub = timezoneOffsetStub(() => '420');
  ...
});
```